# Templates for php files in PHPEd

Tags: php, ide, phpdoc, phped

I want to have some default PHP docblocks in any php file i create, with some licensing info and info about who created the file and so on.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done in PHPEd?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the templates in `c:\Program Files(x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\templates`